# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for 'ComponentName': ([object Object], ?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, angular-components

I dont know why I am getting the error

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ClauseListComponent: ([object Object], ?).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:20399)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:20294)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:19923)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:20494)
at compiler.js:20486
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (compiler.js:20485)
at compiler.js:20456
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I am trying to use ngbModal and here is what i have done so far.

**clause.module.ts**

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ModuleListComponent,ClauseListComponent,ModifyClauseComponent],
  imports: [
    NgbModule
```

**clauselist.html**

```
<ng-template #content let-modal >
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="h4Header" id="modal-basic-title">Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
                        CheckMate!     
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button mat-flat-button class="text-btn" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">ENROLL NOW</button> 
        <button mat-flat-button class="text-btn" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Later</button> 
    </div>
</ng-template>
<button mat-flat-button class="primary-btn marR16" (click)="open(content)">Modal dialog</button>
```

and **.ts file**

```
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(private service : OfferClauseService,private modalService: NgbModal) { }
 open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content,{windowClass:'custom_modal'})
  }
```

**tsconfig**

```
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
```

Counting on ya'll! Please ask if any more clarification is needed.

Comment: Where/how is `OfferClauseService` defined?

Comment: @MenimE did you solve it?

Comment: @Michael can you help me I am getting this error too. with angular 7.2.0

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães unfortunately I couldnt figure it out. I did not use Ngbmodal

Comment: Hi, I solve it when I change to a high version from angular/compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import it in your NgModule instead of injecting it in your component.

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngb-modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ModalModule,
  ],
```

Remove `private modalService: NgbModal` from the constructor:

```
constructor(private service : OfferClauseService,private modalService: NgbModal) { }
```

And instead add `ModalManager`:

```
export class YourComponent {
    @ViewChild('myModal') myModal;
    private modalRef;
    constructor(private modalService: ModalManager){}

    openModal(){
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.myModal, {
        ...
        })
    };
    ...

    closeModal(){
        this.modalService.close(this.modalRef);
        //or this.modalRef.close();
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngb-modal

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your dialog component into `entryComponents` in your module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, ModalComp
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ModalModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ModalComp]
})
```

Comment: It worked for me, Thanks man.  p.s I am trying to add a question but i get "some error in code" message. Google is not helping me, any ideas?